# Outlook Meeting Event onSend

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I m searching a way to detect the click on Send button when on the Appointment/Meeting Request popup. Is there a such event I could possibly manage with C#?

Comment: Can you please add more details on what you need , what you tried and what challenges are you facing ?

Comment: Ok , so I made an add-in which add some visual control in order to generate a message on meeting/appointment, and I want the generation to be mandatory , that's why I want to detect the click on en send button in order to allow or deny it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `Application.ItemSend` event - `MeetingItem` object will be passed as a parameter to your event handler.

Comment: Thank you ! it seems to be the thing i need ... i ll try it

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thank you!